# Auto add-to-cart script for Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I’m trying to build my first script with Selenium and I could need some help.

On my website you can buy event tickets. So as soon as one becomes available I would need my script to check for a specific price and then add it to my shopping cart.

For example let’s say I want a 15,00 € ticket added to my shopping cart:

1. Check the first line of the list to find element that contains “15,00 €”

This is the element:

```
id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl01_Label4”
```

How do I check this element for the text “15,00 €” ?

2. If the button contains the correct price I want the script to click the add-to-cart button next to it:

This is the add-to-cart element:

```
id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl01_LinkButton1”
```

If the price couldn’t be found it should check line two in the list, so

```
id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl02_Label4”
```

and if correct, click on

```
id="ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl02_LinkButton1”
```

How would you write this in Code? This is the first thing I wrote down but I guess it's pretty far off from the right track:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get((‘URL’))

Price = browser.find_element_by_id(‘ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl01_Label4”>15,00 €’)

if elem.is_displayed():

Add = browser.find_element_by_id(‘ctl00_ContentMiddle_TicketList1_GridView1_ctl01_LinkButton1’)
Add.click()
```

Hope someone can guide me in the right direction :)

Best regards
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Checking for a WebElement's text is as simple as it sounds. In your case:

```
Price.text;
```

After that, you probably need an IF to determine if your text has value or not:

```
if Price.text != "15"
{
    //Click add to cart
}

else
{
    //Search for the other element and get text, then check if its "15" etc.
{
```

The only catch here is if the first element's text is, e.g. 13, do you want to search for the next item or not. Adjust the IF above to your needs. Maybe you want to search for the next element only if the first one does not contain text at all.

Comment: Please bear in mind that I'm not coding selenium in python, nor I know the language very well, the code above is a general guideline, so if there are any syntax issues, don't be discouraged. Just correct them on your IDE.